# Bad import in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I install this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps, to create an function to get travel time from google maps, but after launch, my console throw me:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'googlemaps'
```

I try to import like this:

```
import * as google from 'googlemaps';
```

but it not work,

i also try to create `index.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'googlemaps';
```

but without success,

my code:

```
var google = require('googlemaps'); // another try


  async calculateTravelTime() {
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    
    directionsService.route(
        {
            origin: { lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447 },
            destination: { lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511 },
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },
        (response, status) => {
            if(status == "OK") {
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
          }
      )
  }
```

so, how to properly import `googlemaps` in typescript?

thanks for any help

Comment: Did you follow the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/using-typescript#getting_started)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the types of googlemaps.

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

then try again

```
import google from 'googlemaps';
```

or

```
import * as google from 'googlemaps';
```